# Android - Get WebService data to update Map on application initiation

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to update a Map (using Google Maps API V2) when my Android application first starts (and subsequently every 15 secs).

The coordinates are fetched from a REST WebService, from which I am able to get the data (have a button with a listener that makes a webservice call every time it is pressed and displays the data on a Toast).

My problem is that I do not know how to pass the data to the map itself (need to display markers with the location gathered), since I have the WebService call implemented in an AsyncTask.

Right now I have a MainActivity which has a MapFragment in it. Ideally the application would get the data and update all the markers on the MapFragment.

So my question is:

How do I get the data from the AsyncTask? I THINK that once I can get the data I know how to populate the map..

My initial thought process would be to call the AsyncTask in the onCreate() method of my Main Activity and inside that method call another method that would initiate the map, passing the value from the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to update map in 15 sec call AsynchTask in timer like this,

```
public void AsynchTaskTimer() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timer = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        new YourAsynchTask().execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timer, 0, 15000); //execute in every 15sec
}
```

call `AsynchTaskTimer()` in `onCreate()`.
cancel `timer` in `onDestroy()`.

Now in `YourAsynchTask()` call webservice in `doInBackground`, get marker data from webservice fill the ArrayList of marker objects, and pass the ArrayList of marker objects to the method where you display the markers. like this

```
    private class YourAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
   ArrayList<MarkerObject> markerArrList= new ArrayList<MarkerObject>();
markerArrList.clear();
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourMapFragActivity.this, "Wait...",
                        "Loading");
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
                progressDialog.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
                markerArrList=getMapMarkerDataFromWebservice();
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                showMarkerLocationOnMap(markerArrList);
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
```

in `showMarkerLocationOnMap` get one-by-one marker data from `markerArrList` and display on `map`

Hope this helps you.